Why doesn't fast axis stop work when triggered from torque mode in TwinCAT?
I have a motor that I usually control in torque mode using MC_TorqueControl. In order to quickly stop it, my idea was to use the fast axis stop. However, when I trigger the fast stop, nothing happens. Why is that?

If the AX controller is in torque mode, the FastStop of the NC axis has no effect.
You must first switch the operating mode to position or velocity control, because this is not automatically done when the fast stop is triggered.

Thanks for this. Very useful information!
